# Why does Symfony4 give Anonymous user on this ajax request?

Tags: ajax, symfony, symfony4

I use Datatables.net on my Symfony4 app. It sends ajax request with a bunch of POST variables to a controller : UserController->searchApi(). The called URL is `https://127.0.0.1:8000/users-search`. Yet the requested page is redirected to /login page because the Symfony user is anonymous.

So, for debug purpose I disabled redirection, and opened the target page via Firefox devTools. I then can access the debug toolbar, providing useful info :

- Test 1 : I get redirected when i open the POST query to `https://127.0.0.1:8000/users-search` sent by Datatables.
- Test 2 : I do *not* get redirected, and the controller is correctly called when i reach the page by GET
- Test 3 : I do *not* get redirected, and the controller is correctly called when i reach the page by POST when using a form in the page called via GET
- The URL is strictly identical in those 3 use-cases
- The "main" firewall is in use in the redirected page, according to the Symfony debug toolbar. User is, still, anonymous.
- The PHPSESSID cookie is present and accurate in the redirected page, and similar on the accessed page.

It seems the values POSTed by Datatables are the only difference between the tests 1, and 3. So i used Firefox devTools to edit the request sent from the source page (with Datatables on it) and removed the parameters, then re-sent the query. Well it breaks Symfony server without warning and i have to restart it. Odd, but i guess not related.

Here's the security.yml :

```
security:
  encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: auto

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
  providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email

  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      pattern: ^/
      form_login:
        csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

      logout:       true
      anonymous:    true
      guard:
        authenticators:
          - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

      remember_me:
        secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
        lifetime: 3024000 # 5 weeks
        path:     /

  # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
  # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/forgottenPassword$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetPassword/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED }
```

The relevant parts of controllers

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/users", name="app_user_search")
     */
    public function search(UserService $userService)
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('searchUsers');

        return $this->render('user/search.html.twig', []);
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/users-search", name="app_user_search_api")
     */
    public function searchApi(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {

        echo '<form method="post"><input type="submit"></form>';
        die();
    }
```

And the query from Firefox Devtool

```
Request URL:https://127.0.0.1:8000/users-search
Request Method:POST
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Status Code:
200
Version:HTTP/2.0
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

With params (pretty casual)

```
draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=3&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&start=0&length=25&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false
```

---

Edit : the Voter

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security\Voter;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\Voter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserVoter extends Voter
{
    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        // By entity
        if($subject instanceof \App\Entity\User)
            return in_array($attribute, [
                'read',
                'update',
                'delete',
            ]);

        // Not entity-related
        return in_array($attribute, [
            'searchUsers',
            'createUser',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param User $user
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @return bool|mixed
     */
    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $user, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $currentUser = $this->security->getUser();

        // if the user is anonymous, do not grant access
        if (!$currentUser instanceof UserInterface)
            return false;

        switch ($attribute) {
            case 'createUser':
            case 'searchUsers':
                return $this->security->isGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
                    ;
            case 'read':
                return  $user->getCreatedBy() === $currentUser
                    ||  $user === $currentUser
                    ;
            case 'update':
                return  $this->security->isGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
                    ||  $user === $currentUser
                    ;
            case 'delete':
                return  $this->security->isGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
                    &&  $user !== $currentUser
                    ;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the Voter related to the attribute `searchUsers` please

Comment: @qdequippe Yes sir, post edited.